# Unreachable Code on openURL

Tags: java

```
case "Runetrack":
    String inputValue1 = JOptionPane
    .showInputDialog("Please enter your username");
    if (inputValue1.length() == 0) 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a username.",
                            "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
    openUrl("example.com/" + inputValue1);
    break;
```

For some reason it's telling me that the openUrl(""); isn't 'Unreachable Code'. Why and how do I fix this, thanks.

Comment: indent your code and use the code syntax {}

Comment: You can't have code after a return. There is no way it would execute.

Comment: you are calling `openURL()` after a return statement.

Comment: looks like you need braces before and after the 
 if (inputValue1.length() == 0) {
and after return }

Comment: i believe that the return-statement should be inside the if ? then you need to put in inside brackets

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code logic, I'm guessing that the error message and the `return` are conditional. They need to be put inside the flower braces `{}` which constitute a code block and in your code, the code block for the `if` statement.

```
if (inputValue1.length() == 0) { // if block starts
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a username.",
                            "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
} // if block ends

openUrl("example.com/" + inputValue1);
break;
```

The error you're getting is because, any code statement after a `return` statement will not execute the control is returned back to the calling method. Since the `return` wasn't conditional(in the code you posted), the 2 lines of code after that became unreachable, thereby giving the error you see. Once you put that inside the `if` conditional block, it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You already called return, meaning that the execution pointer jumps out of the method. Therefore the code after the return call cannot be executed.

Edit: Maybe you just forgot to add { and } around the corresponding code.

Comment: Thanks, it's all working now. But when I press cancel on the JOptionPane It spits this error; http://pastebin.com/b3DhCcuC

Comment: Look at the pastebin link